# Importing Projects and Building workspace from batch file

Tags: eclipse, batch-file, clearcase, cd

I have this batch file

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO Please Enter Path of the View, you want to update in double quotes.

SET /P variable=
SET ECLIPSE=C:\Users\gdeep\Desktop\TED-4.3.0.20110512190809.lnk
SET WORKSPACE=C:\Users\gdeep\DevCodebase_2

:LOOP
ECHO Press 'g' for Graphical Interface and 'c' for Command line.
SET /P answer=

IF /I "%answer%"=="g" GOTO GRAPHICAL
IF /I "%answer%"=="c" GOTO COMMANDLINE
ECHO Invalid Input. Please Try Again.
GOTO LOOP

:GRAPHICAL
cleartool update -graphical %variable%
GOTO CONTINUE

:COMMANDLINE
cleartool update %variable%
GOTO CONTINUE

:CONTINUE

FOR /D %%i IN (%WORSPACE%) DO RD /S /Q "%%i" DEL /Q "%WORSPACE%\*.*"
START %ECLIPSE% -data %WORSPACE%

D:
chdir "%variable%"\v4electronics

ECHO Please Ensure that Server is killed.
PAUSE
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dresource.minify.skip=true
```

For deleting all the projects i used

```
  FOR /D %%i IN (%WORSPACE%) DO RD /S /Q "%%i" DEL /Q "%WORSPACE%\*.*"
```

Can anyone explain this to me? I copied it from somewhere and don't want to use it without understanding. 
Problem with using above command is althout it seem to work, i see 
      The system cannot find the file specified.
      The system cannot find the path specified.
as the output.
Also, the way i am deleting, will it be equivalent to if i delete them from the eclipse, by select all projects and deleting?

Another problem here is that when i have .

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dresource.minify.skip=true
```

in the end it works fine, otherwise, if there is any other command after it, those commands doesn't run.

After this, I then wanna import all maven projects from the Clearcase %Variable%.
And i want to do that by command line only. Can you help me with that?

Thanks for your help.
Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me, If I'm wrong. I understand that you're in the MS-Windows environment.

Regarding to the question about if there is another command after the "mvn ...", they are ignored.

I use the "call" as the following: -

```
cd project1
call mvn clean install

cd project2
call mvn clean install
```

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: I am in Windows Enviornment. Sorry, i should have explicitely specified that.

Secondly, lemme try 
     call mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dresource.minify.skip=true 
instead of what i was doing..

Are you aware of how to import projects using a clearcase view from command line. If you don't understand what i am talking here is
Right now,
I go to File-> Import-Projects->Maven Existing Projects->Select View

I wanna do this through command line.

Thanks

Comment: I tried using 
     call  mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dresource.minify.skip=true
 i.e, by ading call and it worked. It continued to proces the next commands. Wonder why, it was not processing.

Thanks Charlee.

Do you know how to import projects using command line from a particular Clearcase view?

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience about the Clearcase.

Answer (score 1):

```
 cleartool update -graphical %variable%
```

This will update a view, opening a GUI during the update (if `-graphical` is used) for displaying the number of files unchanged, new, modified, deleted or hijacked during this update.
See [`cleartool update`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_update.htm) man page.

The graphical update will let you specify how you want hijacked files and timestamps handled by said update:

> Click the `Advanced` tab and change default options for the `Update` Tool.
>   If you need to resolve hijacked files, select a method. You have these choices:
>
> - Leave hijacked files in place
> - Rename the hijacked files and load the selected version from the VOB
> - Delete hijacked files and load the selected version from the VOB
>
> You can also select a method for handling timestamps. You have these choices:
>
> - Set file times to current time
> - Set file times to version creation time

You need to enter the path of the root directory of a snapshot view: see "[To update snapshot views](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_update_ssv.htm)"

---

```
FOR /D %%i IN (%WORSPACE%) DO RD /S /Q "%%i" DEL /Q "%WORSPACE%\*.*"
```

This will *completely* empty Eclipse workspace, projects and its `.metadata` folder, forcing Eclipse to recreate a workspace from scratch.
It seems a bit extreme, and would basically be the same as

```
RD /S /Q "%WORSPACE%"
```

(Eclipse would recreate "`%WORSPACE%`" when launched with `-data %WORSPACE%`)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about the update command.

Till the part you have mentioned, i have already succeded till there.
Could you please elaborate about what's the meaning of recreating the workspace from scratch. All i wanna do is delete all projects, metadata and then import all existing maven projects from clearcase view using cmd like File-> Import-Projects->Maven Existing Projects->Select View
One post mentioned that when we open eclipse with  -data %WORSPACE%, all it does is opens eclipse with that workspace? Is that wrong?
 
Thanks.